# Can the EF Fluent API be after database creation

Tags: entity-framework, fluent-interface

My understanding is that the convention is to use the Entity Framework Fluent API in side of the overridden OnModelCreating method in your DBContext method; and that this is only run during db creation.

This would leave me to believe that the Fluent API can only be leveraged more than once(for instance while you're developing your db) if you are dropping and creating your database everytime there are changes.

My question is: Is there a way to leverage the Fluent API for db configuration, for database updates only, for example while running the database migration command "update-database"?

Answer (score 1):

From the [DbContext.OnModelCreating documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of a derived context is created. The model for that context is then cached and is for all further instances of the context in the app domain.

So it is called when the model is created, not just when the database is created. That will happen when you call `Update-Database` after adding a migration, or when you start up your website after publishing a new version.

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6181867/150342

http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/12/entity-framework-migrations-tips/

Comment: Thanks... I guess I'm just trying to determine what the best way is to be able to develop my database as I'm developing the MVC application, adding models, etc.  Seems as though there are two roots, point to an initializer the Drop and Recreates after chages or explicitly apply changes through Data Migrations/Package Manager Console.  The former seems more straight forward to me.  Feedback on preferences appreciated.

Comment: From the elegant code link above. Tip no 1 – "Do not use Automatic Migrations Automatic Migrations are fun for demos and quick proof of concepts, but have no place in a production application"