# OnModelCreating is never called

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am starting work with entity framework.
Problem is that my OnModelCreating method is never called.

this is my context class:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext()
            : base("name=TestDBConnectionString")
        { }

        public DbSet<WorkItem> WorkItems { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Connection string

```
 <add name="TestDBConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I expect to go into OnModelCreating when I call:

```
 using (var context = new TestContext())
        {

        }
```

Where I making mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF 4.1 Code First - OnModelCreating call time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634338/ef-4-1-code-first-onmodelcreating-call-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add a new entity to the context and persist changes.

Like

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    context.WorkItem.Add(new WorkItem()); //Construct valid entity
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

By default strategy, it will try to create a database, if it doesn't exist. Or at least will throw an exception.

Or you can force it to create database at start up

> context.Database.Initialize(true);

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I get exception : An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid.

Comment: Your Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0 appears to be incorrect. What MSSQL version are you using?

Comment: I found solution. In last change I had (LocalDB)\\v11.0 ('\' two times). Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This method is called when the model for a derived context has been initialized, but before the model has been locked down and used to initialize the contex.

Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of a derived context is created. The model for that context is then cached and is for all further instances of the context in the app domain. This caching can be disabled by setting the `ModelCaching` property on the given ModelBuidler, but note that this can seriously degrade performance.
See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx)

If the database doesn't exists it uses information from compiled model to create it. The model is created only once per application. OnModelCreating will never be called when using the Database First approach. It will never be called because all the mappings already exist in the EDMX and so Code First and the DbModelBuilder are never used.

Try to call to the static initializer before making the SetInitializer call:

```
using (var context = new TestContext())
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EntityContext>());
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Comment: How to call it again. My db is not created?

Comment: @Raskolnikov I've updated answer. Try to follow this

Comment: I get exception : An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Specified LocalDB instance name is invalid.

Comment: Perfect explanation!

Comment: This "ModelCaching" property no longer exists.  See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956210/288393 which talks about implementing the property "IDbModelCacheKeyProvider".

Answer (score 8):

In my case this was happening because I had left the { get; set; } off my DBSet declaration. Took a while to figure that out!

Answer (score 0):

As per the official MSDN doc,

It will be called only once as per the default behavior. called only once when the first instance of a derived context is created.