# How to get all data from ef core many to many

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

On EF core have Two tables(Page, Group) both have many to many relations with junction table **GroupPage**. Want to get all pages data with junction table related data based on groupId as like bellow.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a many to many relationship with latest nightly builds of EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442493/how-to-create-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-latest-nightly-builds-of-ef-core)

Comment: https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-1-the-basics/

Answer (score 0):

If you construct your EF relation correctly you should not have a `GroupPage` entity.

See [Entity Framework Database First many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527175/entity-framework-database-first-many-to-many) on how to construct your EF EDM correctly.

Once you have your EDM correctly mapped, you should have the classes

```
public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then you just need to do the following

```
public IQueryable<Page> GetPages(int groupId)
{
    return from group in _context.Groups
           where group.Id == groupId
           from page in group.Pages
           select page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax is self-descriptive. Here are the entities structure and  Page Dto.

```
public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    ...
}


public class PageGroup
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public Page Page { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }   
}


public class PagesDto 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Tab { get; set; }
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDefault { get; set; }

    public PagesDto()
    {
        IsActive = false;
        IsDefault = false;
    }
}
```

Following function help us to get group related pages information.

```
public async Task<List<PagesDto>> GetAllPagesByGroupId(int selectedGroupId)
{
    //get all pages
    var pages = await _pagesRepository.GetAll().Select(p => new PagesDto {
        PageId = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        GroupId = 0

    }).ToListAsync();

    //get group ralated pages
    var selectedGroupPageIds = _groupPagesRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Where(p => p.GroupId == selectedGroupId)
        .Select(p => p.PageId);

    //update page information base on group related pages info.
    foreach (var item in pages.Where(p=>selectedGroupPageIds.Contains(p.PageId)))
    {
        item.GroupId = selectedGroupId;                
    }

    return pages;

}
```