# How to write many to many query in Entity Framework with db first approach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Database model:

```
Create table Author
(
    AuthorID int primary key identity,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)

Create table Book
(
    BookID int primary key identity,
    Name nvarchar(50),
    PageCount int
)

Create table AuthorBook
(
    AuthorID int not null foreign key references Author(AuthorID),
    BookID int not null foreign key references Book(BookID)
)
```

OnModel Creating:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Author> Author { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AuthorBook> AuthorBook { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BookGenre> BookGenre { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Genre> Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MyBook> MyBook { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }
```

There are many to many relationship in book and author tables with the `autor_book` junction table. How do I get books with the authors?

```
using (MyLibraryEntities db = new MyLibraryEntities())
{
    var query = db.Book.SelectMany(book => db.Author, (book, author) =>
            new {
                bookID = book.BookID,
                name = book.Name,
                pageCount = book.PageCount,
                authorId = author.AuthorID,
                authorName = author.Name
            }).ToList<dynamic>();
}
```

I expect to get the list like

```
books = [{"name": book name, "pageCount": 233, authors = {"Carl", "Mike"}, ....].
```

But the actual output is;

```
[{"name": book name", .. author: "Carl"}, {"name": book, ... author: "Mike"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create a relation between Book and Author in Model.
Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/relationships)

Once you create relation, now `Book` entity has Collection of `Author`.
Then query simple as:

```
using (MyLibraryEntities db = new MyLibraryEntities())
{
    var query = db.Book.Select(book =>
            new {
                bookID = book.BookID,
                name = book.Name,
                pageCount = book.PageCount,
                authors = book.Authors.Select(i=>i.Name).ToList()
            }).ToList<dynamic>();
}
```

Comment: Ado.net entity model does not create only two entity within their collections, it also includes the bridge table. What I'm doing wrong? I've added the SQL query for the details.

Comment: Yes, added to question.

Comment: I still get "Book does not contain the definition for Author". Which seems normal since Book class only initialize this.AuthorBook = new HashSet<AuthorBook>(); in its constructor.

Comment: @GONCAŞİLİK could you please add your Book, Author and AuthorBook entities to question.

Comment: System does not allow me to add the whole code. But I think problem is related with wrong relationship. Auto model generation does not create author relation for book, it just add author book. Do I need to add association between book and author with the many multiplicity and delete the author book? What is the cleanest and safest way to generate many to many relationship in database first approach?

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527175/entity-framework-database-first-many-to-many

Comment: Thank you. I just deleted the unique id of bridge tables and get multiplicity but with a warning. However, I don't get the authors rather I get the count of the authors.

authors = Count = 1